# How to use function breakpoint in my application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

So chrome has this feature,

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#function

which allows you to invoke `debug(fn)` on a function and it pause on first line of that function.

But when used in code (not in the console), you would get this error

```
(index):38 Uncaught ReferenceError: debug is not defined
    at window.onload ((index):38)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sxback6v/

How to solve this problem (besides adding a closure with debugger)? I am looking for a way to use the native `debug` function without complaints from the browser.

Comment: How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/v3621qtk/ ?

Comment: @tkausl thanks that's what I'm doing now, though I want a solution that can actually use the debug(fn).

Comment: Well, it's clear that debug is a browser console feature. which is not publicly accessible from within a javascript page. Why are you not happy with the debugger?

Comment: @MosiaThabo The documentation does explicitly mention though "*You can insert `debug()` into your code (like a `console.log()` statement) or call it from the DevTools Console.*" Admittedly that's a bit weird, I'd bet it does at least require the devtools to be opened before being available.

Comment: I'm not content with it mainly b/c I don't understand the concern of the browser as to why they didn't make it a library feature, or I should say make it a regular window method that's accessible to the engine. And if there is a security/design concern, I want to understand why.

Comment: @MosiaThabo its the first link.